# No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: maven-2, teamcity, maven-plugin

Currently, I am using Maven Tool to create a zip file of a downloaded folder from Github https://github.com/Saulis/teamcity-gerrit-trigger

The command that I use is

> mvn [folder name]

However, I faced error while running the command:

> No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project and in the
>   plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available
>   from the repositories)

[image: screenshot]

Is there anyone face the same issue with me? What is this error about?
How can I solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should run maven command in the folder that has `pom.xml`. The syntax pattern is `mvn [task]` (not `mvn` [folder name]). Also if you want to assemble a zip binary, you would want to make sure `maven-assembly-plugin` is used in `pom.xml` as maven does not have zip functionality by default https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html

Comment: I am not sure this will help or not but while installing a local jar into maven I found the same issue and the reason is really silly I had an unwanted space 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<space>C:\MyJar.jar

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the reply @YohanesGultom. 
It really helpful as it correct my mistakes. 
I change directory to the folder that I want to assemble a zip binary with pom.xml in the same hierarchy. Then, I run the command as [> mvn package] and did some changes on proxy settings under C:\Users\ .. \ .m2. Finally, I get the zip binary assembled.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the problem checking for empty spaces e.g. 
`mvn... -Dconfigfile=[unwanted empty space]C:\SOME-DIRECTORY`

Additionally pay attention on `/` and  `\`. This depends on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I resolve it by opening the terminal manually. Just go to your project directory where Pom.xml is and open cmd there. I just hit the same command, and it starts working.

The problem was, I opened powershell instead of cmd.